# Google Map and Web view

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Google Map opening in a Webview using query strings and the API to determine the location.

This worked fine up until a week or so ago; now the window pops up asking what application you would like to use.

Has something changed?  How can I stop this box popping up and have the webview handle the map instead of it trying to open a new browser or Maps?

Relevant code:

```
String detail = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DETAIL);
WebView detailweb   =   (WebView)findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
detailweb.loadData(detail, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using an Intent somewhere. Are you creating your own WebView or are you simply calling an Intent to handle it.

Comment: Have just edited with code thanks